# Neovim: Telescope fails to find `tbl_isarray`

Tags: neovim, lua, plugin-telescope

I run Neovim v0.9.1 using Lua 5.1 (not LuaJIT) and [telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim).
As soon as I invoke `telescope.builtin.git_files`, Neovim shows the following error:

```
E5108: Error executing lua: ...ugins/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/__git.lua:431: attempt to call field 'tbl_isarray' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ...ugins/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/__git.lua:431: in function 'try_worktrees'
        ...ugins/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/__git.lua:477: in function 'set_opts_cwd'
        ...ugins/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/__git.lua:493: in function <...ugins/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/__git.lua:490>
        (tail call): ?
        ...lugins/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/init.lua:580: in function <...lugins/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/init.lua:539>
```

I tried invoking `:lua vim.tbl_isarray()` which gives the same error.
[Neovim's documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#vim.tbl_isarray()) lists `vim.tbl_isarray()`, so I am surprised it is not found.

What am I missing?

Comment: Rather than check the online docs, try your local `:help`. It's possible you need a newer version of NeoVim.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today when I updated my whole Neovim. I rolled Telescope back to version 0.1.2, commit 776b509 https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim/releases/tag/0.1.2

and seems to work again.
I am running on Neovim 0.9.1

On Packer this was something like:

```
use {
  'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', 
   commit = '776b509',
   requires = { {'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'} }
}

-- OR

use {
  'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', 
   tag = '0.1.2',
   requires = { {'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'} }
}
```